# Can I eliminate this linkage in UseExceptionHandler DI

Tags: .net-core, startup, custom-error-handling

I inject a custom error logging and reporting service into my services collection during Startup.ConfigureServices.

```
services.AddTransient<IErrorService, ErrorService>();
```

I then add a global error trap in Startup.Configure.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

Then in Home.Error, I have my DI for ErrorService, and I pass it my context, and all works perfectly.

Is there some way to eliminate the linkage to Home.Error, and just invoke my ErrorService right in Configure?  But I can't figure out how to get linkage to ErrorService at this point in Startup.

Note, two of the other services I inject are my EmailService and my ProgramSettings. I need both of these in ErrorService, so I do need ErrorService invoked in such a way that standard .NET Core DI is wired up.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler(a => {
        a.Run(ctx => {
            var exceptionFeature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

                 ... execute ErrorService here somehow????????

            ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Any luck? Would you be open to an ExceptionFilter?

Comment: I never found a working solution, I still execute /Home/Error.
I am open to any ideas, I would appreciate any ideas you might have.